# MySQL: Find out which store customer spent most money in

Tags: sql, mysql

Making an automated call list to be generated based on certain search criteria that pulls customers names and phone numbers.

There are 4 tables: Customer, Phone_Numbers, Sales_Header, Sales_Detail.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT(customer.First_Name, ‘’, customer.Last_Name), 
       Phone_Numbers.Number, 
       Customer.ID 
FROM Sales_Header 
INNER JOIN Sales_Detail ON Sales_Detail.Header_ID = Sales_Header.ID 
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.ID = Sales_Header.Customer_ID 
INNER JOIN Phone_Numbers ON Phone_Numbers.Customer_ID = Customer.ID 
WHERE Sales_Header.WebSale = -1 
  AND Sales_Detail.Price > 1000 
  AND DateSold > 20081002
```

**Question:**

Each sale in the sales_header has a store location (ID for which store it was sold at).
However customers can buy from more than one store. I need to find out which store the customer spent the most money in, and add that store to the select statement output above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL, I believe it's:

```
SELECT CONCAT(customer.First_Name, ‘’, customer.Last_Name), 
       Phone_Numbers.Number, 
       Customer.ID, Sales_Detail.ID, Sum(Sales_Detail.Price) 
FROM Sales_Header 
INNER JOIN Sales_Detail ON Sales_Detail.Header_ID = Sales_Header.ID 
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.ID = Sales_Header.Customer_ID 
INNER JOIN Phone_Numbers ON Phone_Numbers.Customer_ID = Customer.ID 
WHERE Sales_Header.WebSale = -1 
  AND Sales_Detail.Price > 1000 
  AND DateSold > 20081002
GROUP BY CONCAT(customer.First_Name, ‘’, customer.Last_Name), 
       Phone_Numbers.Number, 
       Customer.ID, Sales_Detail.ID
ORDER BY Sum(Sales_Detail.Price) Desc Limit 1;
```

In SQL Server, you'd do "top 1" before Concat.

Also, depending on how your tables lay out, you'll also want to put a "distinct" (no parentheses or commas before "concat", to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SUM, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY ... does that do the trick?

```
SELECT CONCAT(customer.First_Name, ‘’, customer.Last_Name), 
       Phone_Numbers.Number, 
       Customer.ID,
       SUM(Sales_Detail.Price) AS Total_Purchases
FROM Sales_Header 
INNER JOIN Sales_Detail ON Sales_Detail.Header_ID = Sales_Header.ID 
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.ID = Sales_Header.Customer_ID 
INNER JOIN Phone_Numbers ON Phone_Numbers.Customer_ID = Customer.ID 
WHERE Sales_Header.WebSale = -1 
  AND Sales_Detail.Price > 1000 
  AND DateSold > 20081002
GROUP BY Customer.ID
ORDER BY Total_Purchases
```